# Multiple mapbox instances on android

Tags: android, mapbox

I Need to instances of a map box map. One in an activity and the other one in fragment as a modal overlay. The map in the fragment is white and I see only the current location indicator moving, when I move the map. Is it even possible to have two instances of map box in android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/MapboxGLAndroidSDKTestApp/src/main/res/layout/fragment_dialog_map.xml#L15

```
   mapbox:mapbox_renderTextureMode="true"
```

Put this attribute to your second mapbox view.

Comment: Did you find out another solution to this problem? renderTextureMode = "true" causes a performance penalty:
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/7.1.1/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/MapboxMapOptions.html#textureMode